# C# interface concept clarification with IActionResult in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oop

I'm trying to understand C#, went through the basics and started trying things in ASP.NET Core but couldn't get my head around the interface part.

I understood that an interface is like a contract of what the class should contain and the interface method doesn't have a body, like this for example:

```
interface IAnimal 
{
    void animalSound(); 
}
```

and then we provide the implementation in the class, like this:

```
class Pig : IAnimal 
{
    public void animalSound() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The pig says: wee wee");
    }
}
```

However, when I hit the real world (as usual) things are different :)

In ASP.NET Core we can use the `IActionResult` interface to help us with responses - to return  `Ok()`, `NotFound()`, etc.

Like in this example

```
namespace CityInfo1.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/cities")]
    public class CitiesControllers : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetCities()
        {
            return Ok(CitiesDataStore.Current.Cities);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetCity(int id)
        {
            var cityToReturn = CitiesDataStore.Current.Cities
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            if (cityToReturn == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(cityToReturn);
        }
    }
}
```

But here, `IActionResult` is actually providing the functionality and implementation of different methods.

Another question, in the `IAnimal` example, is it mandatory to use the `AnimalSound()` in the classes that uses this interface? And if so, is it possible to make it optional?

Comment: `IActionResult` is not "providing the implementation of different methods". Why do you think it is?

Comment: where is the functionality or logic of ok() or NotFound() coming from ?

Comment: Aha, so _that_ is your question. They come from [`ControllerBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: If you ever want to know the definition of a method or property, just hilite/select it and hit F12 key

Comment: For your second question, do you mean "is it mandatory to _declare_ the `AnimalSound()` method in the classes that _implement_ the interface"?

Comment: yes - that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IActionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is declared like this:

```
public interface IActionResult
{
    Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context);
}
```

Very similar to your `IAnimal`, isn't it?

There is also a class called [`OkObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0) that implements `IActionResult`, which has this `ExecuteResultAsync` method.

```
public class OkObjectResult : IActionResult {
    public Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

<sub>`OkObjectResult` doesn't actually implement `IActionResult` directly. It inherits from `ObjectResult`, which inherits from `ActionResult`, which implements `IActionResult`. The code is for illustration purposes only.</sub>

This corresponds to the `Pig` class in your non-real-world example.

Now which part of your non-real-world example does your `CitiesController` code correspond to? Well, you missed that part out in your non-real-world example. If we were to continue it, we could say there is a `AnimalFactory` class that produces `IAnimal`s:

```
public class AnimalFactory {
    public IAnimal GetAnimal() {
        return new Pig();
    }
}
```

For the sake of argument, let's say that the users of `AnimalFactory` don't care what kind of animal they get, as long as it is an `IAnimal` - i.e. something that has the `animalSounds` method. We, as the implementers, is free to decide what kind of animal to return, and in this case, I decided to always return a pig.

Going back to your `CitiesController`, you are supposed to return an `IActionResult` in `GetCity`, but the caller doesn't care which specific kind of `IActionResult`, as long as it is an `IActionResult` - has the `ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext)` method. You've decided to return whatever is return by `Ok` (which is a method that `CitiesController` inherit from `BaseController`). And FYI, `OK` returns an instance of `OkObjectResult`. Now you know why I mentioned that at the beginning!

> is it mandatory to declare the `AnimalSound()` method in the classes that implement the interface?

Yes, because by implementing the interface, you are saying that the class has all the members that the interface requires. Declaring that your class implements an interface, then not providing the required members, is just *lying*, isn't it? :D

Comment: oh wow - that's an amazing answer, thanks !
so in the AnimalFactory, the Pig() object is considered an IAnimal as long as it implements the animal sound, right ?

And in the IActionResult, as long as we're returning ok or instance of OkObjectResult then it's considered as an IActionResult like the IAnimal

Comment: @Renm Yes, if you need to return an interface type, you can return any implementation of that interface.

Answer (score 1):

**IActionResult type**

The IActionResult return type is appropriate when multiple `ActionResult` return types are possible in an action. The ActionResult types represent various HTTP status codes. Any non-abstract class deriving from ActionResult qualifies as a valid return type. Some common return types in this category are `BadRequestResult` (400), `NotFoundResult` (404), and `OkObjectResult` (200). Alternatively, convenience methods in the `ControllerBase` class can be used to return ActionResult types from an action. For example, return BadRequest(); is a shorthand form of return new BadRequestResult();.

Because there are multiple return types and paths in this type of action, liberal use of the [ProducesResponseType] attribute is necessary. This attribute produces more descriptive response details for web API help pages generated by tools like Swagger. [ProducesResponseType] indicates the known types and HTTP status codes to be returned by the action.